# Does the spell Dimensional Anchor stop Shadow Jaunt?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, teleportation, tome-of-battle, combat-maneuver

Does the spell Dimensional Anchor stop the ability Shadow Jaunt from the Tome of Battle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The spell [*dimensional anchor*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionalAnchor.htm) may or may not prevent a martial adept from using a maneuver like shadow jaunt

While the spell 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*dimensional anchor*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionalAnchor.htm) [abjur] (*PH* 221) lists some of the spells, spell-like abilities, and psionic abilities that it prevents, the spell also "completely blocks extradimensional travel," which all spells of the [conjuration](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#conjuration) subschool [teleportation](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#teleportation) employ to commit instantaneous transportation, the subschool's description saying, "Teleportation is instantaneous travel through the Astral Plane" (173).

The 2nd-level Shadow Hand maneuver shadow jaunt [special] (*Tome of Battle* 79) *et al.* are presented with the descriptor [teleportation], and the [descriptor] description, says, "Most of these descriptors have no game effect by themselves, but they govern how a maneuver interacts with other maneuvers, powers, spells, or abilities" (44).

So one reading is that because the spell *dimensional anchor* blocks extradimensional movement, and the [teleportation] descriptor indicates that the maneuvers *are* teleportation effects, the maneuvers shadow jaunt *et al.* are blocked by the spell *dimensional anchor*. Another reading says that because the spell *dimensional anchor* lists spells, spell-like abilities, and psionic abilities and shadow jaunt *et al.* aren't any of those *and* that because the teleportation descriptor is otherwise undefined in *Tome of Battle* and used, instead, throughout much of the game's remainder solely as an indicator that a spell or effect is part of that conjuration subschool, the shadow jaunt *et al.*'s descriptor in this context carries very little weight, the spell *dimensional anchor* being unable to prevent the maneuvers' use and likewise allowing teleporation into and within, for example, an area warded by the 6th-level Clr spell [*forbiddance*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/forbiddance.htm) (*PH* 232-3).

Because the official *Tome of Battle* [errata](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111205827/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/errata) document is a [mess](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?460184-Tome-of-Battle-Errata), this is likely to go unresolved except by the DM.

However—and whether this is unintentional or by design, we'll, again, likely never know—, *Tome of Battle* also says, "Unless the description of the specific maneuver or stance says otherwise, treat it as an extraordinary ability" (40), and shadow jaunt *et al.* do *not* say otherwise, making the maneuvers some of the few instantaneous transportation abilities that can be used in, for example, an area affected by the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*antimagic field*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/antimagicField.htm) [abjur] (*PH* 200).

Comment: "Forms of movement barred by a dimensional anchor *include* ... similar spell-like or psionic abilities." It's a list of examples, not a list of every ability the spell covers.

Comment: Designers, line editors, errata compilers, etc. are protected by [Be Nice](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) too, so let's not do that thing.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Changed to *mess*, which, I think, is fair given the document starts with a few lines of *Tome of Battle* errata, transitions to errata for *Complete Mage*, and abruptly ends.

Comment: Yeah, that works!

Comment: @SPavel O, I know, but to extend a list that's comprised exclusively of spells and that ends with "and similar spell-like and psionic abilities" to include extraordinary abilities might seem, to some, an overreach.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes

*Dimensional anchor* does this:

> Any creature or object struck by the ray is covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel.

It goes on to describe examples of things that are extradimensional travel, including *dimension door* and *teleport*. Note that this list is **not exclusive.** It doesn't straight up define what extradimensional travel is, but there's evidence here and there.

For example, the description for spells from the Teleportation subschool says:

> Teleportation is instantaneous travel through the Astral Plane. Anything that blocks astral travel also blocks teleportation.

And what tag does *shadow jaunt* have? [Teleportation]. Therefore, *shadow jaunt* goes through the Astral Plane, making it extradimensional, and blocked.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a tome of battle at hand but Dimension Anchor states:

"Any creature or object struck by the ray is covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel."

It lists some examples which are spells, but it should also block any other teleportation effect. This includes Shadow Jaunt

So yes, Shadow Jaunt is blocked by Dimensional Anchor

Answer (score 1):

Dimensional Anchor reads:

> A green ray springs from your outstretched hand. You must make a ranged touch attack to hit the target. Any creature or object struck by the ray is covered with a shimmering emerald field that completely blocks extradimensional travel. Forms of movement barred by a dimensional anchor include astral projection, blink, dimension door, ethereal jaunt, etherealness, gate, maze, plane shift, shadow walk, teleport, **and similar spell-like or psionic abilities**. The spell also prevents the use of a gate or teleportation circle for the duration of the spell.

(emphasis mine)

A strict RAW reading notes that dimensional anchor does not list Extraordinary Abilities (which shadow jaunt is) and therefore shadow jaunt would not be subject to dimensional anchor (though it would not be unreasonable in my opinion to make dimensional anchor work against shadow jaunt).

Answer (score 1):

The only correct answer is "It is up to the DM to decide"

There is a RAW reading, which clearly allows shadow jaunt through Dimensional Anchor

**Dimensional anchor text**

> Forms of movement barred by a dimensional anchor include astral
>   projection, blink, dimension door, ethereal jaunt, etherealness, gate,
>   maze, plane shift, shadow walk, teleport, and similar spell-like or
>   psionic abilities. The spell also prevents the use of a gate or
>   teleportation circle for the duration of the spell.

**From Tome of Battle**

> Maneuvers are extraordinary abilities unless noted in the maneuver's description.

So by RAW, dimensional anchor cannot stop shadow jaunt as Shadow Jaunt does not mention inter dimensional travel, and is not listed in the included "list of additional things stopped", it doesn't get stopped.

That being said, its not a far reach to assume that its **SUPPOSED** to be blocked by dimensional anchor, by Rules as Intended. It certainly fits the theme of things dimensional anchor stops, and it includes a "teleportation" description on the maneuver.

This is why Rule 0, the DM makes the rules, exists. Its the DMs job to clarify in the grey areas like this.

Personally, as a DM, I would allow them to use shadow jaunt, because honestly, its not going to be a game breaker 9/10 times.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE!  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] page.  Your answer right now is not very good because it doesn't appear to have any sources to back up the claims you make.  Can you cite the RAW reading you referenced in your answer?  Do you have any rules citations that help to explain your stance on the matter?